# How to connect a laser diode?

Tags: power, diodes, laser

I have a circuit fed by a 5V source which receives audio signals, amplifies them, and modulates an LED so the intensity of the LED changes with the voltage.

Ok so far so good. But what I want to do is to replace the LED with a laser diode. I tried and it behaves as LED.

In many websites I came across they are using a capacitor and diode when connecting a laser diode. Should I connect a laser diode in a different way than an LED? Why?

Comment: Duplicate Question? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29218/help-with-laser-diode-connection

Comment: In another question you said you had a "laser module" instead of a raw laser diode. Can you provide a data sheet for your device? It would be very helpful for giving you a useful answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In simplest term no, you dont need to handle it differently

**but**

Laser diodes are usually much more sensitive than regular LEDs. Due to this you will usually see them driven by circuits with capacitors for voltage filtering/smoothing, signal diodes for polarity protection and some form of current limiting, either via a simple resistor or some other means.

So your diode might work but be aware that it might have a low life expectancy.

Resources:

[Laser driver circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17784/laser-driver-circuit)

http://laserpointerforums.com/f42/diy-homemade-laser-diode-driver-26339.html

Answer (score -4):

All LEDs are Intensity proportional to current after the threshold current. THe ESR of the operating point is very low in power LEDs is about .5 Ohm per 1 watt device. or 5 ohm per 100 mW, so keep that into consideration with output driver impedance if using a voltage controlled current source such as one of the above suggested schematics.

Comment: You are giving lots of information in the answers you've been posting; but many of your answers don't address the questions being asked. Here, OP didn't express any confusion about the behavior of LEDs. He asked, how is a laser different?